# Filepath in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, filepath

Following are 2 (MSDS,Shell-CCL) folders in my application

MSDS-->WebContent-->cclFooter.jsp

Shell-CCL-->WebContent-->jsps-->cclTNCDetails.jsp

Now i am currently in cclFooter.jsp
I am trying to access cclTNCDetails.jsp in Shell-CCL folder
I have tried the following but none of them worked. Please explain how to do

```
<a herf="javascript:openLinkFooter('<%= contextpath1%>/../Shell-CCL/jsps/cclTNCDetails.jsp');">Exa</a>
```

where the context path takes me to root/MSDS folder.

```
<a href="javascript:openLinkFooter('/Shell-CCL/jsps/cclTNCDetails.jsp');">Exa</a>
```

But none of them helped. Pls tell me how to navigate to the given file

Comment: Are these both folders under ROOT folder? I mean under same context or different context.

Comment: Put a `../` in front of `<%= context...` maybe...

Comment: @ParkashKumar I am new to this. I will try to explain what it is. So when i am in cclTNCDetails.jsp, the context of the application is www.cclportal-tst.shell.com/Shell-CCL. When i am working in cclFooter.jsp, the context will be  www.cclportal-tst.shell.com/MSDS. So i thinks MSDS and Shell-CCL are like siblings. Pls correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a herf="javascript:openLinkFooter('/Shell-CCL/WebContent/jsps/cclTNCDetails.jsp');">Exa</a>
```

I am not sure, what about the `WebContent` here.